# Where does Eclipse store projects / packages etc?

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I tell eclipse on my desktop to open projects that are saved on my laptop without importing the project?  I want to be able to save on one machine and pick up where I left off on the other.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All projects are saved in the workspace (which saves additional meta data).
A simple solution for you would be to save the workspace on dropbox or similar and let eclipse load the work space from the drop-box folder.

Another option would be to use version control which is common in pratice (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), e.g. git (github.com).

Comment: @ verbose-mode. Thanks. This is what I was looking for.  Before I do this, I'm obviously making copy of the workspace folder and putting it on my desktop.  But can you please let me know if this is the proper way to have Eclipse call the dropbox "workspace" folder instead of the local?  1) move the workspace folder to drop box.  2) Create an alias of the workspace folder. 3) Move "workspace alias" folder back to /user/documents/workspace.  4) change the folder name from "workspace alias" to "workspace" 5) Re-open Eclipse.

Comment: You can just move the workspace folder to the drop box abdi tell eclipse to use this one. I guess it will be cleaber to create a new workspace in the drop box and import the old projects into this

Comment: That was my original question:  how do you tell eclipse to use a different workspace location. I can't find it in settings.

Comment: File -> switch workspace  http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-workspaceswitch.htm

Answer (score 1):

All of the details end up in the workspace itself.  So the workspace needs to be in a location that is shared between the two machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a *workspace* on each machine linking to the same *project* files. The most convenient way is creating the project in a shared location (e.g. an external hard disk) rather than inside the workspace folder, then doing "import existing projects" on the other machine (with an independent Eclipse installation and workspace).

At this point you only need to keep in sync two Eclipse installation (same installations, removals and updates of plugins) and two workspaces (typically, you can set up one, export the configuration and import it in the other installation).

I would be uncomfortable sharing a workspace along with projects:

- some settings might need to differ between workspaces. Common case: web proxy configuration.
- Two workspaces can include different projects.
- If you don't have exactly the same version of the same plugins, two Eclipse installations could fight to rewrite workspace settings to their liking.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox is a good option.

I would import the project into eclipse on my laptop as well as on my desktop, with the common dropbox folder as the workspace, so that everything is synced.

For instance, if I make changes to my code on my desktop, dropbox should automatically sync those changes. After that, when I open up the same code on my laptop using eclipse, I would make sure to go to my project explorer, click on the project and manually refresh (press F5). Be sure to refresh!

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you do it is stored in your workspace located in the user folder in the drive where OS is installed. You can find it simply here in your own pc
C:\Users\PCname\workspace\buky\bin

Comment: Finally, the answer!

Answer (score 0):

According to your scenario, I think the best option for you would be using a **distributed version system**. This way, you could have both projects on different machines under different **local** repositories (you don't even *need* to have a central repository or something similar), pushing changes as you work on them.

That being said, I would recommend you taking 30 minutes to read [this Mercurial Tutorial](http://hginit.com).

Answer (score 0):

The workspace saves this information, but it also saves a lot of other metadata that you may not want to share between different computers. Such as where dialogs are seen, what perspectives are open etc. If the Eclipse are of different versions, you may end up with the newer version converting the workspace to a later configuration and rendering it unusable to the older version.

The best way to share projects between computers is to use [project sets](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-cvs-project-set.htm). This will also work for sharing projects between different users. This in turn required a source repository, which is something you should always consider using.