# Sharing an Eclipse workspace across computers?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to design or use 5 to 10 PCs (with eclipse) but with the same workspace, how can I do that? I already tried but I can not share the folder of the workspace, please help

Comment: Have you tried dropbox ? Or just Git ?

Comment: +1 for the Git suggestion. You won't get far without Version Control there. Copy/pasting your workspace will sooner or later result in different states and is just tiresome. You could try to run Eclipse directly from a USB stick, but this is likely to slow down your IDE.

Comment: thank you for your information , But can you tell me more about Git, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [One eclipse workspace, simultaneously open on two machines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991611/one-eclipse-workspace-simultaneously-open-on-two-machines)

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to achieve, actually?

Because the workspace is supposed to be user specific. It contains things like settings, how perspectives are setup, which view to show where. Which means if two users share a workspace they will continually write of each others settings.

And to enforce this, as soon as you starts Eclipse with a workspace, it is locked preventing someone else to use it.

So sharing workspace is not a good idea.

What I guess you really want to achieve is to share the projects between several developers. Using project sets is a good way to do that. Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21683508/207764) for a different question regarding this.

If you want to share preferences with other users, then check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881655/importing-exporting-project-preferences/881720) for advice on import/export of preferences.

Comment: thnx for your answer, i need to work at one work space same time in different PC , for example in Java project each PC can add the Classes for the same project