# One eclipse workspace, simultaneously open on two machines

Tags: eclipse, sharepoint, network-share

I have an eclipse workspace located on a server and a friend and I would like to be able to simultaneously work on a project at the same time. The problem I run into is that once I open the workspace on one computer it won't allow you to open it on the other computer (will throw an error saying it is already open). We are currently using dropbox but would like the server since that would be instant instead of waiting for dropbox to sync.

Comment: This is intended behaviour; A w0rkspace should per user and are not meant to be shared.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, you can't have one Eclipse workspace open simultaneously on two machines.

That's why coding projects use either Subversion or Git.  I'm not familiar with Git.  Subversion allows multiple people to make a copy of the project.  When you want to commit your changes to Subversion, Subversion manages any source conflicts.

Afterwards, you update your project to bring in the other person's (people's) code changes, so that you workspace copies of the project remain synchronized.

I'm sure Git does the same thing, just using different terms.  [GitHub](https://github.com/) is one web site that allows you to host public projects for free and lets you use either a Git or a Subversion connection tool.